# linux nohup command with redirection

Tags: linux, jboss7.x, io-redirection, nohup

cannot figure out which is the correct way to start jboss EAP 6.1 in RedHat Linux.

```
nohup ./dev/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.sh 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

or

```
nohup ./dev/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

To me the latter makes more sense, but I found the first one when I googled.

Additionally, is one of the above the correct way to start jboss in the server so that it does not quit when I log out?
Or is there a better way (like, sudo something) ?

-SGB.

Comment: `< /dev/null` will look for input from the null device. If the script is looking for input and blocks waiting for something on input, this is probably not what you want. `> /dev/null` will send the output to the null device ("run quietly"). The `2>&1` means that `stderr` output will be send to `stdout`. I'm not familiar with jboss, so I'm uncertain whether this is the right way to run it in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`, you can issue:

```
nohup ./dev/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You probably want to read about [I/O Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) as well.

Comment: thanks devnull .... for the link on IO redirection. It was a good refresher. thanks!